# How do I determine the current user in batch?

Tags: batch-file, directory

I'm making some installation systems, and I want it to find the current user, and go to the user's folder. So for example, if the current user is Joe, then I want it to change the directory to Joe's folder instead of Mary's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%username%` system variable contains the current user name.

You can also use `%userprofile%` as a substitute for `C:\Users\<user>`

Answer (score 0):

I would say that depends totally on the System you use:

For the Username:

- Windows: `echo %username%`
- Linux: `echo "$USER"`
- Java: `System.getProperty("user.name")`

For the User-Home-Directory:

- Windows: `echo %userprofile%`
- Linux: `echo "$HOME"`
- Java: `System.getProperty("user.home")`

(`echo` is just the command to print something)

Comment: Batch is exclusive to Windows.